# Error executing Bash command in Pig script

Tags: bash, unix, apache-pig

I haven been trying to execute the following code on a Pig script:

```
%declare OLD_YEARS `echo $(for i in $(seq 0 3); do date -d "2018-11-19 ${i} years ago" +%Y; done | awk '$1 <= 2017'| paste -s -d ,)`;
```

When i execute the shell command it returns the results as expected:

```
$ echo $(for i in $(seq 0 3); do date -d "2018-11-19 ${i} years ago" +%Y; done | awk '$1 <= 2017'| paste -s -d ,)
2017,2016,2015
```

But when i execute this on Grunt shell it keeps returning the following error:

```
grunt> %declare OLD_YEARS `echo $(for i in $(seq 0 3); do date -d "2018-11-19 ${i} years ago" +%Y; done | awk '$1 <= 2017'| paste -s -d ,)`;
2018-11-29 19:10:53,904 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext - Undefined parameter : i
```

Can someone shed some light on this ?

Thank you in advance.

** EDIT **

Just to add that my Pig version is 0.12.0 and it is running under the CDH 5.14.2.

Comment: It sounds like `grunt` is trying to expand `${i}` before the command runs.

Comment: any idea why this is happening and how i could resolve this ? By the way, i am running Pig **v0.12.0**

Comment: My guess would be to escape the `$` (`... \${i} ...`), but I don't know exactly how Grunt deals with its input.